# Can't add an xmlns:xlink as an attribute.

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am making an XSLT 2.0 that takes in an xml and spits out smaller parsed xmls. One of the elements needs to look like this

```
<article xml:lang="en" article-type="editorial"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

I created the xml:lang as an attribute, same with the article-type. but when I try to do the xmlns:xlink, it tells me that xmlns:xlink is an invalid name for an attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the namespace (`xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`) to your `xsl:stylesheet`.

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also, if you're trying to add this to an element without typing it in directly, use `xsl:namespace`:

```
<article>
  <xsl:namespace name="xlink" select="'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'"/>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answer by DevNull, provided that the name of the element to be generated is known in advanced (not dynamically computed), you can just have in your code:

```
<article  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
  <!-- Create necessary attributes here -->
</article>
```

It is quite possible in this case to simplify the creation of the attributes, if their names are known in advance, even if their values are dynamically computed:

```
<article  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="{$vLang}" 
          article-type="{$vartType}" > 
  <!-- Generate any content here -->
</article>
```